# Cannot generate reports from SQL Management Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-collection

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 and have installed the MDW on one server and have a Data Collector collecting and uploading the server activity, query results, and Disk activity data to the MDW. When I select any of the reports from the MDW with Data Collection > Reports > Management Data Warehouse I receive the error:

> *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - > Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

This occurs for all 3 reports and after I've waiting some time and data has been uploaded from the data collector. I do not have SSRS running, but read that isn't necessary.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed Service Pack 2 on your server, but more importantly on your workstation (or wherever you're running the reports within Management Studio)? e.g. this one was fixed in a CU for SP1 (but you should install SP2 anyway): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2639301

Comment: Can you get any more error information, like a call stack? Is there anything in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: If you have changed the database name recently. Reconfigure the datacollection set

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into and resolved this issue today.  Select the View Logs context menu option in the Data Collection Sets--the data upload could have failed, which causes the reports to generate this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into problems on this version where I had to go to each data collector explicitly and select 'Collect and Upload Now'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  this is probably going to be removed.  I do not think it has anything to do with the setup of the MDW but with SSMS itself.  I downloaded the latest beta release of SSMS (2015) and was able to view the reports with that.